# Linux mint GParted partitioning during installation can't see mount point option

Tags: linux, partitioning, linux-mint, gparted

I am trying to install Linux Mint Debian Edition 5 on Acer's laptop. I made a bootable USB stick with the ISO downloaded from the official website.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fOHjqllzTy0&t=1s

I want to split the drive into a separate partition for the home folder since it does make a lot of sense to me.

However, for me, the interface looks different (see picture here (sorry for the phone photo))
[image]

There is no "use as" and "mount point" options, instead, there are "partition name" and "label" input fields.

What went wrong? I this a new version of GParted or I did do something wrong?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. This is the first time I install Linux on live hardware.

SOLVED: Partition editor on the video is not GParted. I have created partition using GParted, than I've discovered that by using right-click created partition in the installer I can assign a mount point to it.

Comment: 1. A separated /home used to make more sense that nowadays. It's purpose was to keep personal files and settings for a reinstallation that reused the partitions. For some distros (e.g. Ubuntu) that experimented a lot of changes regarding their desktop environments in recent years, keeping certain settings isn't advisable and can be quite counterproductive and create issues down the line. 2. About personal files: If they're important you should have backups, end of the story. This automatically makes the whole point of having a separated /home partition moot. (...)

Comment: @ChanganAuto Thanks for the information!

Comment: 3. GParted is pretty much the same as it ever was and never had the options you mentioned and wouldn't make sense either. With Gparted you can manage partitions (create, delete, resize, etc.) but **it's within the installer that you can choose choose "use as" when manually partitioning**.  That part of the installer isn't GParted and Gparted isn't even required to create partitions during the installation.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Yea, you've right, I didn't notice that on the video they didn't use GParted at all in the first place, but some other utility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The video doesn't show starting GParted, but the installer. You're following different steps, so don't expect the same results.

"Use as" and "Mount point" are options of the installer, not GParted. From GParted's perspective it doesn't matter what purpose the partition will serve or where it will me mounted.

You have two options:

1. First create partitions using GParted, then assign them in the installer.
2. Avoid GParted and use the installer for partitioning.

Personally I prefer option 1.

That being said, a separate `/home` has valid use cases, but much more rarely than it used to (just like separate data partitions in the Windows world). Btrfs and ZFS subvolumes may be a good compromise in some cases. For a beginner a single partition is definitely what I would recommend.

Comment: Yes! I've found that on the installer window you can right-click partition and assign a mount point for it.

Answer (score 2):

There is a "Use as" option in GParted, it's just labelled "File system" instead.

However, the program shown in the YouTube video is not GParted in the first place. It's another partition editor, perhaps using the same libparted under the hood, but a whole different app built specifically for *OS installer* use – fields such as "Mount point" only make sense because the *installer* will generate configs like /etc/fstab after the partitioning.

Actual GParted as in your <del>screenshot</del> photo, however, is created as *just* a partition editor and doesn't have the ability to update /etc/fstab; all of its features only alter the disk itself, not OS configuration.

(There is no *fundamental* reason why GParted couldn't edit fstab if asked, that feature just wasn't programmed into it. The simpler "GNOME Disks" partition editor *does* support adding fstab entries via GUI.)